# Why is this query on a MEMORY table slower then its twin on InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, performance, memory, innodb

I have an InnoDB and MEMORY version of a table. Both have the same indexes and the same 30,000 rows of data. There's a particular query that runs very slow when run executed against the MEMORY table.

Here's against InnoDB:

```
SELECT emails.id
FROM emails
LEFT JOIN custom_data_person pd1 ON (pd1.person_id = emails.person_id)
WHERE pd1.field_id = 13

2928 rows in set (0.24 sec)

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pd1
         type: ref
possible_keys: person_id,field_id
          key: field_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: const
         rows: 20240
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: emails
         type: ref
possible_keys: person_id
          key: person_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: test.pd1.person_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
```

Here's MEMORY:

```
SELECT emails.id
FROM emails_memory AS emails
LEFT JOIN custom_data_person pd1 ON (pd1.person_id = emails.person_id)
WHERE pd1.field_id = 13

2928 rows in set (1.40 sec)

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: emails
         type: ALL
possible_keys: person_id
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 30000
        Extra: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pd1
         type: ref
possible_keys: person_id,field_id
          key: person_id
      key_len: 10
          ref: test.emails.person_id,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

(Note that the person_id index is a BTREE index. I tried the same with the default HASH index and the results were the same.)

So it appears MySQL optimized the second query in a different way which made it perform worse. Why is that? Can I "fix" it?

Comment: Can you do an `explain tablename` and `show indexes from tablename` on the 2 different tables. 2 different engines will optimise differently so you may need to provide hints to the engine

Answer (score 2):

You don't really care. With a tiny table with 30,000 rows, anything is going to be very fast, even a table scan.

However, it looks like it's chosen a different explain plan. In the innodb case, it's used the custom_data_person table first, and used a covering index. It then queries the emails table for each row found in the custom_data_person table. This seems like the sane explain plan.

It's possibly some bad pessimisation in the optimiser for memory tables.

I'd steer clear of memory tables. If you want a table which behaves almost like a memory table, use a MyISAM table and truncate it on server startup. Memory tables suck incredibly badly because they store varchars padded to maximum length, so they usually use a lot more memory than another type of table. MyISAM uses storage very efficiently. Alternatively, use InnoDB tables for everything.

Unfortunately innodb doesn't provide a way to set durability on a per-table basis, so if the fsync on each transaction bothers you, you have to do bigger (and hence fewer) transactions.

Using several engines is a compromise, as there is rarely any way the server can automatically divide up its (finite) ram between the engines. So you usually want to use just one engine; this includes the memory engine which will happily take away heaps of memory from your innodb (hence make it slower as it can fit less of your db in memory) if you configure it that way.

Seriously though, you really, really, really don't care for 30k rows. 30k rows can fit in the smallest memory even if they're vast. Any engine is a memory engine when you use 30k rows.

Comment: There are perfectly valid reasons for using memory tables.

Comment: I have never quite understood what they are.

Comment: for temporary tables in stored procedures, heap is better.. It seems to take 1/2 second for "create table" to complete, if it is an INNODB table.  Also, deleting say 1/2 the rows in a BIG table (lets say 1,000,000 rows) takes a long time.  while that sounds ridiculous, its actually necessary for me to periodically do so.  Your comment about using several engines - does that degrade performance in any way?  you mention memory (I get that) but what about joining Innodb tables to MyISAM tables is there a penalty for stuff like that?

Comment: It is true that some InnoDB metadata operations can be slow. DROP TABLE is particularly bad when you have a huge buffer pool (it needs to scan the whole buffer pool to identify pages to discard)